# Since when do absolute positioned elements grow the document

Tags: css, positioning

I just stumbled over a strange behaviour.

I have a div which is positioned absolute. The element is positioned to lay outside the body and the document grows.

That's confusing to me, since I always thought, that absolute positioned elements get out of the flow.

Has this changed somewhen or do I get something wrong?

I tested it in Chrome 51 and FF 46.

HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  position: absolute; 
  width: 100%;
  right: -2em;
  top: 102vh;
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h6qys3wg/1/).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what exactly you want with the div behavior??

Comment: I expect that the document doesn't grow when the child is absolute positioned.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```